# Combining polylines if they meet specific conditions?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, merge

I want to combine the polylines in one shp if they are connecting, having the same names and same values. The same names and same values are based on two fields of the table, as shown below. Is there any existing built-in tool I can use?
[image]

I am using ArcGIS 10.3.1 Advanced License.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this I would try concatenating the two fields using the Field Calculator or ArcPy and then dissolving on the concatenated field.

As commented by @Fezter there is probably no "need to concatenate. [Dissolve](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm) tool works on multiple fields."  I have not tested to confirm.

Comment: I don't think there's a need to concatenate.  Dissolve tool works on multiple fields.